# Prevent Word Wrap Using Prism.js

Tags: javascript, css, ghost-blog

My blog is powered by [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) and [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com/) is used for syntax highlighting. This works great, but I'd like to disable word wrap to make code snippets easier to read. Is there a Prism.js configuration setting I can toggle or can this be fixed by making a change to the blog's stylesheet? I've experimented with the `white-space` property, but I haven't been able to make it work. To see an example of the problem, you can visit [this blog post](http://bartjacobs.com/core-data-fundamentals-working-with-managed-objects/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `word-wrap` CSS attribute against the `pre` and `code` blocks to `normal`. For example:

```
code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

As far as I can tell this is part of the default CSS (http://prismjs.com/download.html) so perhaps it was mistakenly removed while customizing the prism styles.

Comment: Great. That does the trick, Anthony. I didn't modify what I downloaded from the Prism.js website, but it's possible that Ghost adds a few customizations of its own.

Comment: Glad it worked :) If it can be tracked down to the Ghost set up process (I'm not familiar with Ghost other than I've heard of it) it would be worth reporting it as an issue on the project page as I'm sure this is something other users will run into.

Comment: `code[class*="language-"] { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to include any child elements as well using *, like this:

```css
code[class*="language-"],
code[class*="language-"] *,
pre[class*="language-"] {
    word-wrap: normal;
    word-break: normal;
}
```